# In Python how to unzip a single file inside a zip file in a url?

Tags: python, zip

In Python 3 I have a program to extract files from a zip in a link (zipurl):

```
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipurl = (f'http://agencia.tse.jus.br/estatistica/sead/odsele/prestacao_contas/prestacao_final_2014.zip')

with urlopen(zipurl) as zipresp:
    with ZipFile(BytesIO(zipresp.read())) as zfile:
        zfile.extractall('doacoes_2014')
```

Please, is there a way to unzip only one file? In case I need the file "receitas_candidatos_2014_brasil.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ZipFile.extract()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract) to extract a single file instead of [.extractall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall):

```
zfile.extract('receitas_candidatos_2014_brasil.txt', 'doacoes_2014')
```